# Keyword "class" in declaration

Tags: java

I faced a rather simple question in an interview.

**Why do we use the `class` keyword for declaring classes?**

Comment: A good question, I think so. I think if the IDE can look at the source code and say, oh, it is a class, not an interface. we never need to do so anymore:)

Comment: Because declaring them as apples would be more confusing?

Comment: So what did you guess?  I assume you didn't feel that it was the "right" one, but surely you said something?

Comment: I just couldn't answer anything convincing at that moment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: **because that's the way it's done in C++**. Java has taken the bulk of its syntax from C++ - a wise decision, in my opinion, as it really helped with drawing programmers when it was still new.

Now, if your question is why a keyword is needed at all - i.e. why can't the compiler just deduce where classes are declared - maybe it can, but using a keyword has the benefits of

1. Being easier to compile.
2. Being more readable to humans than implicit declarations.
3. As I said above - being similar to C++ syntax.

**EDIT:** one other things - some things simply *cannot* be deduced by the compiler in the Java syntax - for example, the only difference between an empty class and an empty interface (both legal in Java) is the `class` / `interface` keyword.

Comment: "Being more readable to humans than implicit declarations" +1!

Answer (score 3):

To better resolve ambiguity. A .java file can either be an interface, an enum or a class. How would you,for example distinguish between an `interface` and an `abstract class` with no method bodies?

The Java compiler simply doesn't work that way - i.e. go through the declaration and then see what it could possibly be. Not saying it can't, it's just designed that way.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simply for readability.

- If a class is being declared, use `class` keyword.
- It an enum is being declared, use `enum` keyword.
- If an interface is being declared, use `interface` keyword.

Keywords play very important role in a computer language, and the more explicit and obvious its meanings are, the better. Naming them inconsistently would do more harm than good.

The full list of keywords is given in the Java Language Specification:

#### [JLS 3.9 Keywords](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.9)

> The following character sequences, formed from ASCII letters, are reserved for use as keywords and cannot be used as identifiers:
>
> ```
>         abstract    continue    for           new          switch
>         assert      default     if            package      synchronized
>         boolean     do          goto          private      this
>         break       double      implements    protected    throw
>         byte        else        import        public       throws
>         case        enum        instanceof    return       transient
>         catch       extends     int           short        try
>         char        final       interface     static       void 
>         class       finally     long          strictfp     volatile
>         const       float       native        super        while
> ```
>
> The keywords `const` and `goto` are reserved, even though they are not currently used.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Keyword (computer programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyword_(computer_programming))

#### Related questions

- [Why does a programming language need keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452365/why-does-a-programming-language-need-keywords)
- [Avoiding Language Keyword Conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145353/avoiding-language-keyword-conflicts)

Answer (score 1):

To separate it from interfaces/methods, thereby saying that there is a possiblity that it can be instantiated somewhere else (if it is not abstract etc).

Answer (score 1):

Because it's a lot simpler for the compiler to validate source code against the grammar for valid syntax allowed in a class versus valid syntax allowed in an interface/enum/attribute definition if you explicitly give it this information, rather than the compiler having to have the intelligence to infer this.